# Theano config directly in script

Tags: python, theano

I'm new to Theano and I wonder how to configure the default setting directly from script (without setting envir. variables). E.g. this is a working solution ([source](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html)):

```
$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python check1.py
```

I intend to come up with the identical solution that is executed by only:

```
$ python check1.py
```

and the additional parameters are set directly in the script itself. E.g. somehow like this:

```
import theano
theano.set('mode', 'FAST_RUN')
theano.set('device', 'gpu')
theano.set('floatX', 'float32')
# rest of the script
```

Is it even possible? I read the [config page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) which provides the information that allows me to read the already set values (but not to set them by myself).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$ THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python check1.py
```

All you're actually doing is setting an environment variable before running the Python script.

You can set environment variables in Python too. For example, the `THEANO_FLAGS` environment variable can be set inside Python like this:

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32"
```

Note that some Theano config variables cannot be changed after importing Theano so this is fine:

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32"
import theano
```

But this will not work as expected:

```
import theano
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32"
```