# theano gpu not working on the google colab

Tags: python, gpu, theano, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a theano code on the gpu using google colab but it doesn't work. Here is my code which is picked up from the [Tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) and expected to print out `Used the gpu` while it is out put is `Used the cpu`. I used this [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988334/theano-config-directly-in-script) question to configure gpu in run time mode. Here is my code and it's out put:

(*Just in case, I have configured my notebook to use the gpu*)

**code:**

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32"
import theano


from theano import function, config, shared, tensor
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], tensor.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, tensor.Elemwise) and
              ('Gpu' not in type(x.op).__name__)
              for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

**OUt put:**

```
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 4.432506 seconds
Result is [1.23178032 1.61879341 1.52278065 ... 2.20771815 2.29967753 1.62323285]
Used the cpu
```

Comment: i am also stuck with the same issue. Could you find your answer?